# Is this queen endgame a win or a draw for White?

Tags: analysis, draw, queen-endgame

```
[FEN "6k1/8/4qp1p/7P/6P1/5P2/6K1/Q7 w - - 0 1"]
```

I am unable to analyze this queen endgame in which it is White's turn. Is it a win or a draw for White?

Answer (score 3):

I analyzed your position with Stockfish 11 ("Stockfish_20011801_x64_modern" to be exact) to a depth of 78 and it returned the following line as the best continuation.

```
6k1/8/4qp1p/7P/6P1/5P2/6K1/Q7 w - - 0 1

1. Qa8+ Kf7 2. Qb7+ Kg8 3.Qb8+ Kf7 4. Qb1 Qe2+ 5. Kg3 Qe5+ 6. Kf2 Qh2+ 7. Ke3 Qe5+ 8. Qe4 Qc5+ 9. Ke2 Qb5+ 10. Kf2 Qb2+ 11. Kg3 Qa1 12. Qc4+ Ke7 13. Qc7+ Ke6 14. Kg2 Qb2+ 15.Kh3 Qf2 16. Qc4+ Kd6 17. Qe4 Qg1 18. Qb4+ Ke6 19. Qc4+ Ke7 20. Qd3 Qh1+ 21.Kg3 Qa1 22. Qe3+ Kd7 23. Qe4 Qa5 24. Qd3+ Ke6 25. Qe3+ Kd7 26.Kh3 Qb5 27.Qe4 Qf1+ 28. Kg3 Kd6 29. Kf4 Qb5 30. Qd4+ Ke7 31.Qe3+ Kf7 32.Kg3 Qb8+ 33.Qf4 Qb6 34. Qc4+ Kg7 35. Kf4 Qb8+ 36. Ke3 Qa7+ 37. Qd4 Qb7 38.Kf2 Qc7 39.Qb4 Qh2+ 40. Ke3 Qg1+ 41. Ke4 Qa7 42. Qd6 Qa4+ 43. Ke3 Qb3+ 44.Qd3 Qe6+ 45. Kd2 Qa2+ 46. Ke1 Qa1+ 47. Kf2 Qb2+ 48. Kg3 Qb8+ 49. Kg2 Kf7 *
```

As you can see by playing through the variation, no progress ends up being made and the game one way or another ends up drawn through the 50-move rule (I say one way or another because white theoretically could push say the f pawn at the end of the variation showed and restart the 50-move rule).